# "unnecessary string to number conversion" in ksh script

Tags: scripting, shell, comparison, ksh

I'm doing some scripting in the Korn shell, and I can't work out how to avoid the warning "variable expansion requires unnecessary string to number conversion". My code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/ksh
testnum=04
(( $testnum == 4 ))
```

The error's being spotted on that third line. I've tried adding `integer testnum`, but that appears to make no difference.

Comment: That's a wonderful message. "requires" and "unnecessary" referring to the same thing.

Comment: @bmargulies: Isn't it just? I tried Googling it, but the only hits I could find were for the (very dense and seemingly uncommented) code that generates it.

Comment: This must be version-specific. For me, "Version JM 93t+ 2009-05-01" doesn't issue this error. Nor do pdksh or mksh. What version are you running?

Comment: From ksh93 source code, this warning message appeared in the very last version (93t+ 2010-06-21). http://ksh.sourcearchive.com/documentation/93tplus-p20100621/lexstates_8c-source.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this message to mean you are converting testnum to a string by using $testnum in the numerical part of your script which is unnecessary. You probably won't have this message when using this syntax:

```
#!/bin/ksh
testnum=04
(( testnum == 4 ))
```

Comment: Within the "(( ... ))", arithmetic expressions are expected. The shell syntax is somewhat different there and in particular, variables are automatically expanded. Note that the $ is required in some cases, like if you need to reference a script argument (eg: $1).